# Combine a column in select statement if multiple data is present

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a requirement where i have a select statement like below:

```
SELECT t1.a,t2.b,t2.c FROM t1,t2 WHERE t1.d = t2.e group by a,b;
```

I am fetching column `'b'` and grouping it with column `'a'`. However, the no of lines in table `t2` can be multiple for one count of column `t1.a` and `t2.b` can be different in each case. 
So for one count of `t1.a`, **if multiple `t2.b` is there, i want it to be shown as "MULTIPLE" otherwise, it should show the value of `t2.b`**.

I hope my question is clear. 
Thanks in advance,

Anoop

My Query:

```
select prh.requisition_header_id,
case when count(prl.suggested_vendor_name)>1 THEN 'MULTIPLE' ELSE prl.suggested_vendor_name END suggested_vendor_name
from PO_REQ_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL prd,PO.PO_REQUISITION_LINES_ALL prl, gl_code_combinations gcc,fnd_flex_values_vl f1,
fnd_flex_values_vl f2,PO_REQUISITION_HEADERS_ALL prh,PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F papf
where prd.requisition_line_id = prl.requisition_line_id
and prl.requisition_header_id = prh.requisition_header_id
AND PAPF.PERSON_ID = PRL.TO_PERSON_ID 
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAPF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAPF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
and gcc.code_combination_id = prd.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
and gcc.segment1 = f1.flex_value
and gcc.segment2 = f2.flex_value
and f1.flex_value_set_id = 1
and f2.flex_value_set_id = 2
and prh.AUTHORIZATION_STATUS IN('APPROVED','IN PROCESS')
and prh.preparer_id = 35016
group by prh.requisition_header_id,gcc.segment1,gcc.segment2,f2.description,prh.requisition_header_id,
papf.full_name ,prl.suggested_vendor_name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response guys,

The final answer that worked include the following logic:

```
decode(count(distinct prl.suggested_vendor_name) over (partition by prh.requisition_header_id),1,prl.suggested_vendor_name,0,null,'MULTIPLE')
vendor
```

I used `partition by` to group the vendors and `decode` to show the required result

Answer (score 1):

The closest approach i was able to find is the one stated down below. Just note that i've removed all the boilerplate you posted to improve readability.

```
select case 
         when vendors.vendorsqty > 1 then 'MULTIPLE'
         else (select suggested_vendor_name 
                 from po_requisition_lines_all
                where requisition_header_id = vendors.headerid)
       end
  from (select prh.requisition_header_id headerid,
               count(prl.suggested_vendor_name) vendorsqty
          from PO_REQUISITION_HEADERS_ALL  prh,      
               PO_REQUISITION_LINES_ALL    prl
         where prl.requisition_header_id = prh.requisition_header_id
         group by prh.requisition_header_id) vendors;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying to group all values in t1.a column into one single string? Then you use CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(t1.a), GROUP_CONCAT(t2.b)) Or you just want to concat two values? if so, you use CONCAT(t1.a, t2.b)

Comment: No. I want to group the values in table2 with respect to table1. But if for a unique entry in table1, there are multiple entries in table2, i want it to come in a single row with the value of the column as "MULTIPLE" rather than it showing up in multiple rows as is the real behaviour of the ordinary group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT t1.a,CASE WHEN COUNT(t2.b) > 1 THEN "MULTIPLE" ELSE t2.b END FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 
ON t1.d = t2.e 
GROUP BY t1.a;
```

- Note implicit join is discouraged

Comment: Showing the count is ok, but if i want to show the field also, it will give me a "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression" or the result set that should come even if there is no case statement. I guess i have to use inner queries?

Comment: I have added the query to the question

Comment: Ok now tell me which field you need to show? you already get t2.b if count is just one, so do you expect now?

Comment: i need to show prl.suggested_vendor_name. If there is only one prl.suggested_vendor_name for a prh.requisition_header_id, then prl.suggested_vendor_name should be shown. Else 'MULTIPLE' should be shown with prh.requisition_header_id.

Comment: Use concat t1.a with MULTIPLE instead of just MULTIPLE?

Comment: lets say i have 10 rows in table1 and 15 rows in table2 where 5 rows in table one has two related entries in table two. So the result will have the column in table2 having "MULTIPLE" shown 5 times and the real value of the column shown for the remaining 5 rows. But, instead, i am getting 15 rows.

Comment: @SMA This won't work because you also got to group your `t2.b` (in your `case` `else`). However, if you do that you'll also get an error because `t2.b` is not explicitly defined in your `select` clause.